# How to generate a Jlist with alternating colors

Tags: java, swing, jlist

In Java how do I get a `JList` with alternating colors? Any sample code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To customize the look of a `JList` cells you need to write your own implementation of a [`ListCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).

A sample implementation of the `class` may look like this: (rough sketch, not tested)

```
public class MyListCellThing extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

    public MyListCellThing() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        // Assumes the stuff in the list has a pretty toString
        setText(value.toString());

        // based on the index you set the color.  This produces the every other effect.
        if (index % 2 == 0) setBackground(Color.RED);
        else setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        return this;
    }
}
```

To use this renderer, in your `JList`'s constructor put this code:

```
setCellRenderer(new MyListCellThing());
```

To change the behavior of the cell based on selected and has focus, use the provided boolean values.

Comment: Careful, you need to handle the case where the row is selected (color changes then)

Comment: yeah, I mentioned that in the bottom of the post.

Comment: Minor nitpick: should be setBackground rather than setBackgroundColor.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you extend `DefaultListCellRenderer` rather than implementing the interface directly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270023/java-list-set-background-of-list-item.

Comment: @DuncanJones do you know what you gain by doing that?

Comment: I've found that it avoids the issue of having to hand-code the correct behavior when the item is selected. The default class will automatically do what's correct for the current look and feel.

Comment: +1 for the setCellRenderer() tip. I was extending JList and trying to use my new class instead of JList<String>. All I needed to do was set the renderer to a custom one. Thanks.

Comment: While extending `DefaultListCellRenderer` has the benefit of dealing with reasonable UI defaults, it should be noted that `DefaultListCellRenderer` is not generic / type safe. One has to chose, either UI defaults, or generics.