# JList where each line might need to have a different font-color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlist

I am a newbie here just joined this wonderfull community. I have to admit this is the best site out there for programming questions and answers. Now let me get to the point:

I am trying to create a JList where I can input lines with different font colors taken from a ColorChooser. I have tried something already as described below

Thank you in advance for any answers.
Best regards,
dwc

Here is my sample code:

```
class CustomObject
{
    String s;
    Color color;
    String scolor;

    public CustomObject(Color color, String s)
    {
        this.s = s;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor()
    {
        return scolor = Integer.toString(color.getRGB());
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return s + color.getRGB();
    }

}

class myListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{

Color color;

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
{
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    if (value != null)
    {
        CustomObject o = (CustomObject)value;
        setText(o.getData());
        color = new Color(Integer.parseInt(o.getColor()));
        setForeground(color);
    }
    return this;
}
}
```

My main problem is that I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to app.CustomObject
```

in the line:

```
CustomObject o = (CustomObject)value;
```

Comment: possible dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076473/how-to-generate-a-jlist-with-alternating-colors

Comment: I have checked that solution, I am just not sure how to actually manually give the color I want to use in each case, unlike that example.

Comment: That is not a SSCCE. How do I compile that? Where do you build the CustomObject and add it to the model? Did you not see the SSCCE I provided you in the link below? Also why does the getColor method return a String, the setForeground() method expects a Color object. Since you pass in a Color object why are you converting it back and forth to a String/Color?

Comment: Yes this is just the fragment of the code, I don't have the time to read the SSCCE page you gave me, so I just pasted the code. 
Shouldn't this be enough since the problem is originating here?
Yeah the getColor method needs a revision, but it's irrelevant to the problem. 

The uncompilable line is:    CustomObject o = (CustomObject)value;

Comment: And I don't have time to create a test program. By definition, until the problem is solved you don't know what part of the code is causing the problem so you don't know what is or isn't relevant code to solve the problem. The problem is obviously the data you add to the model (you think you added a CustomObject but the code is telling you that a String was added) and you have not posted that code. Good luck I've tried to help but I don't have time to play 20 questions which is why I asked for the SSCCE!

Comment: You are absolutely right mate. Thank you for teaching me how to make SSCCE. I just read it and made a new post and got my answer. 

Thank you for your time and patience!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want each line to have a different background color then you need to store that information in the model. So instead of simply storing a String in the model you store a custom Object that contains two properties, the Color and the Text. Then your custom renderer uses the Color to set the background of the line and the Text to set the value of the line.

This [posting](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=57&threadID=613731) shows an example of using this approach. The example is for a combo box but the concept is identical.

Edit: I believe this was the original example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ComboBoxColor extends JFrame
{
    public ComboBoxColor()
    {
        Object[] items = { Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue };
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( items );
        comboBox.setRenderer( new ColorRenderer( comboBox) );
        getContentPane().add( comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        add( new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ComboBoxColor frame = new ComboBoxColor();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    class ColorRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
    {
        JComboBox comboBox;
        Border border;


        public ColorRenderer(JComboBox comboBox)
        {
            this.comboBox = comboBox;
            border = new LineBorder( Color.WHITE );
        }

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
        {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            setText( value.toString() );

            if (!isSelected)
                setBackground( (Color)value );

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: camickr can you please show my how the custom renderer is going to work? I know I am asking too much but as I said I am kind of new to Java not so experienced in writing custom code...

Comment: You where given a link to an example renderer that alternates the color of lines. So the code is not that much different. You cast the value to your "custom Object". Then you set the background using the Color of you custom Object. Then you set the text of the label using the text of your custom Object. If you need more help then post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org). Note also that you should extend the default renderer, not a JLabel.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work right now, but I am facing some problems with this line:

CustomObject o = (CustomObject)value;

for some bizzare reason I get the exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to app.CustomObject

Comment: Well you can't add a String to the ListModel. You need to add a CustomObject to the model. I gave you a working example. I'm not a mind reader I can't guess what you are doing and you haven't posted a SSCCE, so I can't offer any more help.

Comment: Ok ok you are right, let me post my SSCCE then, do I just put it in a comment here or edit my first post?

Comment: Dead link. What was the title of this post, does anyone know/remember?