# Java List set Background of list item

Tags: java, list, applet, awt

How does one change the background color of a Java AWT List item? By that I mean a single item in a AWT List, not the whole thing.

Comment: Touche, but I have looked and I'm about a helpless as a short man trying to jump over a building :(

Comment: you need to learn not to be so "helpless".  Either that or you need to stay out of software development.

Comment: OK I quit. I'm now going to wash dishes for the rest of my life. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a custom renderer. That is, if you're using Swing. It's better to stick with the Swing components and not the awt gui components.

```
JList
...
setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
...
class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
  {
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    Color bg = <calculated color based on value>;
    setBackground(bg);
    setOpaque(true); // otherwise, it's transparent
    return this;  // DefaultListCellRenderer derived from JLabel, DefaultListCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent returns this as well.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java AWT List inherits from Component, use Component's setBackground(Color c) method.

```
List coloredList = new List(4, false);
Color c = new Color(Color.green);
coloredList.add("Hello World")
coloredList.setBackground(c);
```

List now has a color green.

Comment: That would do the WHOLE list. I want the background of the double-clicked list item to change not the whole list.

Comment: Add that to your question then :)

Comment: Yeah, now I'm trying to figure out how to set the rows of a List because new List(4,false); ain't working :P haha woo!

Comment: Well thats probably because I put the List in the EAST BorderLayout so it streches anyway... ugh! I dunno.

Comment: The question wasn't accurate to begin with, but now it is. Either adjust your answer or delete it.

Answer (score -1):

Been a while since I have worked with AWT, but can't you just use setBackground(Color)?  List is a subclass of java.awt.Component.