# JList text color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlist, defaultlistmodel

Is there a way to change the text color of a specific element on a JList?

like this:

one(Black)

two(Blue)

three(Black)

four(Blue)

five(Blue)

six(Black)

using a DefaultListModel and the data are coming from a DB...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a Jlist with alternating colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076473/how-to-generate-a-jlist-with-alternating-colors)

Comment: Given the colors are purely alternating, note that is the default for a `JTable` when shown using the Nimbus PLAF.  E.G. as seen in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11279610/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model only stores the data, not the color of the data.

You need to render the data differently for each cell. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more information and an example.